# Procedure not working using "IF"

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have the fallowing procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_comments
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE var INT;
SELECT grade INTO var FROM table1;

    IF (var <= 7) THEN
        UPDATE table2 set comment = not_good;
    ELSE
        UPDATE table2 set comment = good;
    END IF;
END$$
```

comment, not_good and good are all columns from table2

but it gives me the error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS
BEGIN

    IF (var <= 7) 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE table2 set comment ' at line 3
```

Can't find out the problem, can someone help me with this?
Thanks!

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Your code is product specific.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_comments
AS
BEGIN
```

With

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_comments()
BEGIN
```

PS: add brackets and remove "AS"

Comment: @RodrigoDomingues - If it worked, please explain how `not_good` passed a syntax check without quotes.

Comment: actually **good** and **not_good** are columns, it retrieves their values

Answer (score 0):

Remove that `AS` operator from your procedure code body. Your procedure should look like

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_comments
BEGIN
DECLARE var INT;
SELECT grade INTO var FROM table1;

    IF (var <= 7) THEN
        UPDATE table2 set comment = not_good;
    ELSE
        UPDATE table2 set comment = good;
    END IF;
END$$
```

Refer [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html) for more information